# osmdroid define a button to go back to initial center

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have an activity with an osmdroid mapview and a button
what I want to do is when I click the button the mapview center goes back to the center that I initialised in the activitiy's onCreate method
please could someone tell me how could I do that?

Comment: You can provide some sample code. So that people can understand your question better and answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapView.scrollTo(x, y)` in the button's OnClickListener.
There is also `mapView.getController().animateTo()` and `mapView.getController().setCenter()`.